# Owl Carousel : How to slide two carousel sliders at a same time?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am looking to slide contents of 2 sliders at a time, just like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cv9zpypr/31/), with only one 'prev' and 'next' button. But I am not sure how to assign click event to prev/next button in owl carousel.

Here is my pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POqazz

can anyone correct this code:

```
 $('.owl-next').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble with your owl carousel version but it is working. Here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POqBje?editors=1111

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var o2 = $('#c2')
  o2.owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    singleItem:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,    
    //dots:false,
    pagination:false,
    navigation :true,
    touchDrag: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    afterMove: function (elem) {
      var current = this.currentItem;
      o1.trigger('owl.goTo',current);
    }
});

    var o1 = $('#c1');
    o1.owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    singleItem:true,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,    
    //dots:false,
    pagination:false,
    navigation :true,
    touchDrag: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    afterMove: function (elem) {
      var current = this.currentItem;
      o2.trigger('owl.goTo',current);
    }
});




});
```

Comment: is there any way that I can create independent nav buttons (prev, next) below both sliders that will control both sliders ?

Comment: hide one and style the other buttons with css

Comment: this same thing not working owl-carousel 2 when use `#c2` slideby 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936542/owl-carousel-slider-on-drag-and-dot-click-not-working