# owl-carousel slider on drag and dot click not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm using Two owl carousel sliders with one navigation for my bootstrap website. In the below code prev and next is working perfectly.

The problem that the `ondrag` and `owl-dots` functions are not working. When I click the dot and drag the first slider (`work-class1`) the second slider should slide same like prev and next arrow.

```js
var o2 = $('#work-class2')
o2.owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  dots: false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 2,
  mouseDrag: false
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1');
o1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 0,
  //dots:false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 1,
  mouseDrag: true
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1'),
  o2 = $('#work-class2');
  
//Sync o2 by o1
o1.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o2.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o1.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o2.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});

//Sync o1 by o2
o2.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o1.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o2.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o1.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next span,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev span,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.owl-dot span {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class1" id="work-class1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class2" id="work-class2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the second slider slide 2/2 . first slider 1/1 in same time when we navigate both slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just changed the second carousel options into an object and referenced that to determine how many slides to switch the secondary carousel by with a translate.owl.carousel call.

```js
var o2 = $('#work-class2')
var o2settings = {
  items: 2,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  dots: false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 2,
  mouseDrag: false
};
o2.owlCarousel(o2settings);

var o1 = $('#work-class1');
o1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  singleItem: true,
  loop: false,
  margin: 0,
  //dots:false,
  pagination: false,
  nav: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  slideBy: 1,
  mouseDrag: true
});

var o1 = $('#work-class1'),
  o2 = $('#work-class2');
  
//Sync o2 by o1
o1.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o2.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o1.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o2.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});

o1.on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  o2.trigger('to.owl.carousel',e.page.index * o2settings.slideBy);
});
//Sync o1 by o2
o2.on('click onDragged', '.owl-next', function() {
  o1.trigger('next.owl.carousel')
});

o2.on('click dragged.owl.carousel', '.owl-prev', function() {
  o1.trigger('prev.owl.carousel')
});
```

```css
.owl-dot span {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next span,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev span,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class1" id="work-class1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="owl-carousel work-class2" id="work-class2">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://www.idaconcpts.com/wp-content/testing-website-optimization.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

//for drag use this event

```
mouseDrag: true,
```

//for dot click

note: Please replace this code in your custom navigation slider button

```
    <div class="owl-dots">
      <button role="button" class="owl-next own-custome-trigger">
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <button role="button" class="owl-prev own-custome-trigger">
        <span> </span>
      </button>
   </div>
```

//css for dots

```
.own-custome-trigger {
background: red;
display: inline-block;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
border: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-right: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

Comment: Not working. My concern is when I drag first slide second slide will slideby 2. And first slide slideby 1 as same as `prev,next` button.

Comment: I check it I think that is not possible because you use two sliders in different div's first in div column 4 and another in div column 8. I don't know why you do this but you should have to use only one slider if you want action on the whole carousel on a single click or drag

Comment: But when click its working fine. I want the same action when I drag also. Its my client expectation.